# Stop refreshing data everytime in gridview on tab changed using fragment

Tags: android, gridview, tabs, android-fragments

Hi i am making tab using fragment. Here is my code to generate the tabing:

```
   private static void addTab(QatarAuctionHomeTabActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();


    tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);
        ft.commit();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

Here is my onTabChanged() listener

```
 public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);

            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
       // ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

I am adding a fragment with Gridview in it(fetching data from web to load the grid). But my problem is when i navigate between the tabs and go to the grid tab again every time data is loaded. The onCreateview() is called and data loads every time. Here is the code of grid view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_layout, container,
            false);
    Log.e("oncreateview", "Aise");
    initiateServerParameters();
    getUserDataFromPreference();
    initialize();
    setUpGrid();
    requestDataFromWeb();
    return view;
}
```

I know ft.attach(newTab.fragment) method recreate the view of the fragment again and that causes the call of oncreateview() method. But i dont want to load the data every time. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

Use onCreate method of fragment to hit webservice and set adapter only if list is null or updated... 
Right now you are doing this in OnCreateView, which is called everytime u select the tab.

Comment: Where should i initialize all my views. if i do it in oncreate() it shows nullpointer exceptions cause oncreateview not yet called. Can you give me a code snippet?